# Xamarin Android: efficient way to create a copy of some entries of a SQLite DB table

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sqlite

I have a Xamarin (C#) Android app that handles some customer information. I have the following method that is reading from a SQLite DB (the connection is stored in the global variable *globalVars.Db*) some quotes for a specific customer (with the name stored in another global variable, *globalVars.Customer*). 
Given the number *n* that I pass to this method, I just want to create n copies of this customer information to the same table of the DB, after having replaced the customer name with more generic names (like "*Default customer 1*", "*Default customer 2*", etc).
The code below works as expected, but seems to be relatively slow especially when n is 3 or more. 
Is there a more efficient way to achieve my goal?

```
private void cloneCustomer(int n)
    {
        var tableQuotes = from d in globalVars.Db.Table<dbQuotes>()
                          where d.CustomerName == globalVars.Customer
                          select d;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            foreach (var quote in tableQuotes)
            {
                quote.CustomerName = "Default customer " + i;
                globalVars.Db.Insert(quote);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the insert loop block into a single transaction

```
private void cloneCustomer(int n)
    {
        var tableQuotes = from d in globalVars.Db.Table<dbQuotes>()
                          where d.CustomerName == globalVars.Customer
                          select d;

        globalVars.Db.RunInTransaction(() => {

          for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            foreach (var quote in tableQuotes){              
                quote.CustomerName = "Default customer " + i;
                globalVars.Db.Insert(quote);
             }
           }

       });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What does this change do?

Comment: This will wrap each Insert's transaction invocation from the loop into a single transaction. This should speed the insertion process